# Mapping keys to multiple keys and associated values with python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Here is the following test code:

```
dict1 = {'k1': '{v1}', 'k2':'{v2}', 'k3':'{v3}' , 'k3':'{v4}'}
list1 = ['k1_1', 'k2_2', 'k3_3', 'k3_4']

newdict = {}
for items in list1:
    val = items.split('_')[0]
    if val in dict1.keys():
        newdict[items] = dict1[val]
```

This yields:

```
{'k1_1': '{v1}', 'k2_2': '{v2}', 'k3_3': '{v4}', 'k3_4': '{v4}'}
```

What I really want is:

```
{'k1_1': '{v1}', 'k2_2': '{v2}', 'k3_3': '{v3}', 'k3_4': '{v4}'}
```

The above code works like a charm when there is only one-one mapping from the list and keys in dictionary.
What modification can I make to ensure that the values are preserved after the exchange in keys takes place?

Comment: No, if you notice, the value for key 'k3_3' is not the same. I would like the value to remain the same in the output, currently it takes the latest value and assigns it to all keys 'k3_*'

Comment: @heemayl I thought that too, but the desired one has `’k3_3’: ‘v3’` instead of `’k3_3’: ‘v4’`

Comment: `dict1` is incorrectly defined. You can not have duplicate keys. Try printing it after you define it and you will see that the value for `'k3'` is `'{v4}'`.

Comment: Yes, look at your `dict1` directly after you define it. You overwrote `{v3}` immediately. https://repl.it/repls/MonumentalCoralSubversion

Comment: do you know you **can not** have `'k3'` as key twice in your dict? Key are unique in dictionary. Even though you can declare it , but last value with that key  will override all the previous values

Comment: You could use a list of tuples instead of a dict: `[('k1','{v1}'),...]`

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, your dictionary is attempting to store multiple keys of the same value, which will only add the final stored key's value. Instead, you can use a list of tuples:

```
d = [('k1', '{v1}'), ('k2', '{v2}'), ('k3', '{v3}') , ('k3', '{v4}')]
list1 = ['k1_1', 'k2_2', 'k3_3', 'k3_4']
list1 = iter(list1)
new_d = [(next(list1), b) for _, b in d]
```

Output:

```
[('k1_1', '{v1}'), ('k2_2', '{v2}'), ('k3_3', '{v3}'), ('k3_4', '{v4}')]
```

Answer (score 0):

This wont work because `dict1` is not a valid [`dict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Per the docs:

> It is best to think of a dictionary as an unordered set of key: value pairs, **with the requirement that the keys are unique (within one dictionary)**. A pair of braces creates an empty dictionary: `{}`. Placing a comma-separated list of key:value pairs within the braces adds initial key:value pairs to the dictionary; this is also the way dictionaries are written on output.

How do you expect Python to know which `'k3'` you are referring to?

Comment: The statement **is not a valid** looks incorrect to me. The dictionary in question is having a correct structure but doesn't behaves the way OP expects it to be.

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri No, it is not valid, the documentation specifies the requirements for a validly _defined_ dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, dictionaries do not allow you to store duplicate keys, so you have to follow a different approach. One is to trick your dictionary into seeing your keys not as `strings`, but instances of a class, sharing the same name. The following is an example with your sample case:

```
# Create a class that overrides the 'repr' method in order to print the actual key.
class Key:

   def __init__(self, name):
      self.name = name

   def __repr__(self):
      return self.name

# Create instances of the 'Key' class as keys.
dict1 = {Key('k1'): '{v1}', Key('k2'):'{v2}', Key('k3'):'{v3}' , Key('k3'):'{v4}'}
list1 = ['k1_1', 'k2_2', 'k3_3', 'k3_4']

print(dict1.keys())

dict1 = dict(zip(list1, dict1.values()))

print(dict1)
```

Output:

```
dict_keys([k1, k2, k3, k3])
{'k1_1': '{v1}', 'k2_2': '{v2}', 'k3_3': '{v3}', 'k3_4': '{v4}'}
```

Credits go [here](http://www.wellho.net/mouth/3934_Multiple-identical-keys-in-a-Python-dict-yes-you-can-.html) for the initial idea.